# Template with boost::operators extremely verbose and repeating

Tags: c++, template, boost

I got the following ugly code:

```
template < class _Coeff,
       unsigned _nVars,
       typename _Expo=int,
       template <class, class> class _Map = _Map >
class Polynomial
      : boost::ring_operators< Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>
      , boost::addable       < Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>, _Coeff
      , boost::addable       < Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>,
                   std::pair< std::array<_Expo,_nVars>, _Coeff >
      , boost::subtractable  < Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>, _Coeff
      , boost::subtractable  < Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>,
                   std::pair< std::array<_Expo,_nVars>, _Coeff >
      , boost::multipliable  < Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>, _Coeff
      , boost::multipliable  < Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>,
                   std::pair< std::array<_Expo,_nVars>,_Coeff >
                > > > > > > > {
```

In particular, I hate to repeat `Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>`. Is there a way to improve this syntax without using the preprocessor ? I can't manage to get any help from the `using` keyword here.

Just for the infos: I'm writing multivariate polynomials where `_Coeff` is the class of the coefficients and the terms `X1^4x2^4` are represented as `std::array<_Expo,_nVars>`.

Answer (score 2):

Easy, with default template arguments:

```
template < class _Coeff,
       unsigned _nVars,
       typename _Expo=int,
       template <class, class> class _Map = _Map
       typename Poly = Polynomial<_Coeff,_nVars,_Expo,_Map>,
       typename Pair = std::pair< std::array<_Expo,_nVars>, _Coeff > >
class Polynomial
      : boost::ring_operators< Poly
      , boost::addable       < Poly, _Coeff
      , boost::addable       < Poly, Pair
      , boost::subtractable  < Poly, _Coeff
      , boost::subtractable  < Poly, Pair
      , boost::multipliable  < Poly, _Coeff
      , boost::multipliable  < Poly, Pair
                > > > > > > > {
```

Comment: I don't like it that much because it expose non-sensical parameter to the user. But then I can re-hide them by a front-end using template... OK !

Comment: @hivert Indeed I, would also name this `Polynomial_Impl` or something, then add a template alias to this. The remaining default template arguments would go to the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: Add a `std::enable_if` at the end to check the user did not change those extra parameters