# In-place reversal of a singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

As suggested in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14590911#14590911), I'd like a review of this in-place reversal of a singly linked-list:

```
#include <iostream>

struct node { 
    int data;
    node *next;
};

node *reverse(node *list) { 
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *next;

    while (list) {
        next = list->next;
        list->next = prev;
        prev = list;
        list = next;
    }
    return prev;
}

void show_list(node *list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        std::cout << list->data << ", ";
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *list = NULL;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        node *n = new node;
        n->next = list;
        n->data = i;
        list = n;
    }

    std::cout << "As built: ";
    show_list(list);

    list = reverse(list);

    std::cout << "Reversed: ";
    show_list(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use the term one pass reversal rather than in-pace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code of actual reversal is fine, so like previous answers I only have a some suggestions on general style. As discussed by [Corbin](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45977/39083), raw memory management is very error prone, and you should avoid it at any cost. It is even more dangerous in the presence of exceptions; even if your code is bug-free, you can still have leaks. Without trying to change the logic too much, below are some minimal changes that will help you organize code better. Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a476c336b2bade2).

---

**Node data structure**:

```
template<typename T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node *next;

    explicit node(T&& d = T{}, node *n = nullptr) :
        data(std::move(d)), next(n) { }

    explicit node(const T& d, node *n = nullptr) :
        data(d), next(n) { }
};
```

A node is now a class template over the value type `T`. A couple of constructors make it easier and safer to construct a new node. In case `T` has move semantics, separate move and copy constructors will be more efficient. Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

---

**Actual reversal**:

```
template<typename T, typename N = node<T> >
N *reverse(node<T> *list)
{
    N *prev = nullptr;

    while(list)
    {
        N *next = list->next;
        list->next = prev;
        prev = list;
        list = next;
    }

    return prev;
}
```

Use type aliases like `N` to make code more compact. A default template argument is maybe my personal style of saving lines of code. You will probably find this unclear, so use an explicit `using N = node<T>;` declaration instead. Keeping declarations at first use like `N *next` make code clearer. Don't worry about efficiency here, leave this to the optimizer.

---

**Streaming**:

```
template<typename S, typename T>
void show_node(S& s, node<T> *&list)
{
    s << list->data;
    list = list->next;
}

template<typename S, typename T>
S& operator<<(S& s, node<T> *list)
{
    if (list)
        show_node(s, list);

    while (list)
    {
        s << ", ";
        show_node(s, list);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Overload `operator<<` for streaming. Print separators only between elements, not at the end of the sequence. If this leads to code duplication, use an auxiliary function like `show_node()`.

---

**List management**:

```
template<typename T, typename N = node<T> >
N *make_list(size_t L)
{
    N *list = nullptr;

    for (size_t i=0; i<L; ++i)
        list = new N{T(i), list};

    return list;
}

template<typename T, typename N = node<T> >
void delete_list(node<T> *list)
{
    while (list)
    {
        N *next = list->next;
        delete list;
        list = next;
    }
}
```

As a minimal protection against bugs, define individual functions to generate and to clear a list. See now how convenient is `node`'s constructor (`new N{T(i), list}`). Note that `T(i)` assumes a `size_t can be implicitly converted to`T`. In more realistic example you should be careful about conversions.

---

**Main**:

```
int main()
{
    auto list = make_list<int>(10);
    std::cout << "As built: " << list << std::endl;

    list = reverse(list);
    std::cout << "Reversed: " << list << std::endl;

    delete_list(list);
}
```

Using list management functions and streaming operator, `main()` is now cleaned up. The very next step would be to make sure `delete_list` is automatically called at end of scope, but as I said I am not changing the logic too much here.

Comment: Though there's a lot of good advice in here, I'm afraid this answer is a bit impractical if the question asker weren't a known C++ expert. All kinds of C++11 features are strewn through this with no mention of that (especially since the OP is likely using 03). Also, a default template argument to save a few characters is odd. What in the world is the user supposed to think N is? And why can it vary? That's an inappropriate shortening in my opinion. Use 'using' or typedef if you want to alias a type. Don't expose laziness to the caller.

Comment: Just read that comment back to myself, and it was a bit unclear. To be a bit clearer, the impracticality isn't the C++ features but themselves but the relatively steep learning curve of templates, rvalue references, and move construction thrown at a question that exhibits very little understanding of more advanced features of C++. Then again, I suppose maybe I should stop trying to pretend the knowledge level of the question actually matches the knowledge level of its asker :)

Comment: @Corbin Criticism accepted :-) I clarified a bit more the use of a default template argument in the answer. I am usually carried away by uses where it is [really convenient](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45358/39083).

Comment: the issue with the default template argument isn't the lack of clarity. It's the ruining of the public signature that's the issue. An unnecessary template parameter is confusing to the person using the function. A `using` declaration isn't just clearer: I consider it the correct approach in this situation. There are situations like you linked to where you could just wrap it in another function to hide the extraneous template params, but that seems overkill for such a perfect use case for `using`.

Comment: @Corbin What can I say, you're right! Feel free to edit if you like.

Answer (score 8):

- You don't use `delete` after allocating `node`s with `new`, resulting in a memory leak.  As a general rule, `delete` should be used in the same way `new` was used.

  In this case, have an identical `for` loop and use `delete` on each node:

  ```
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      delete n;
  }
  ```

  With these two loops, you might as well have a constant to hold the number of nodes to use, so that you can make sure the same number is used.
- You don't need to have `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  Reaching the end implies successful completion, and the compiler will insert this return for you.

Answer (score 7):

I think there are a few points worth mentioning that I haven't seen in any replies yet.

```
struct node { 
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

As @Edward mentioned, this should almost certainly be a template. The `next` pointer should almost certainly be a `unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.

```
node *reverse(node *list) { 
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *next;

    while (list) {
        next = list->next;
        list->next = prev;
        prev = list;
        list = next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Although a couple of people mentioned exceptions, nobody mentioned the fact that this code isn't re-entrant. If an exception is thrown while the list is being reversed, the list will typically be left in a bad state--in particular, part of it may be orphaned. The reversal is done by traversing the list, and manipulating each node's pointer to point to the previous node instead of the next one. While this is being done, the list is basically broken into two pieces. An exception thrown in the middle of that process is likely to "lose" one of the pieces.

Likewise, making this thread safe (by almost any reasonable definition of the term) basically requires that the *entire* reversal process be treated as a single critical section. That is to say, no other thread can be allowed to read part of the list at any point in the reversal process. This is likely to be a serious problem if there is much contention for use of such a collection.

```
void show_list(node *list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        std::cout << list->data << ", ";
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

This displays a comma and space after the final item in the list. It would be better to provide access to the items in the list via iterators. With iterators, it would be trivial to use something like an [infix_ostream_iterator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489) to display the data more neatly.

```
node *list = NULL;
```

As @iavr showed, it's better to use `nullptr` instead of NULL. While `NULL` works perfectly well to produce a null pointer, it can also be used by accident in places that aren't related to pointers at all (because `NULL` is simply a macro for the value `0`). By contrast, `nullptr` can be assigned to any pointer, but not to other types such as integers.

Overall, this code should clearly be avoided for almost anything except its originally intended use (in-place reversal of a linked list).

Since @David K mentioned the possibility of using `std::list`, and `std::slist`, I'll point out yet one more possibility. If you honestly need to a linked list (you probably don't) *and* need to traverse in both directions, *and* you really can't afford a doubly-linked list like `std::list`, there is one other possibility that may be worth considering: a doubly linked list that stores only *one* link per node.

Although thoroughly crufty in some ways, this structure is just clever enough to be worth mentioning in this context. To store both backward and forward links in only one link field, what we store in the node is actually the exclusive-or of the addresses of the previous and next nodes in the list. The parent linked-list typically stores a dummy node containing pointers to the first and last nodes in the list.

We can then use those pointers to recover the rest of the pointers. We have the address of node A, and the XOR of the addresses of node A and node B. Xoring those two together gives us the address of node B. That node, of course, contains the XOR of the addresses of node B and node C. Since we already have the address of node B, we can XOR it with the value from the node to get the address of node C (and so on for the remaining nodes in the list).

Conversely, if we start with the address of node Z and the XOR of the addresses of node Z and node Y, we can use exactly the same procedure to isolate the address of node Y. That, in turn, is enough to recover the address of node X, and so on through the list in reverse.

This obviously has its own set of strengths and weaknesses. The most obvious weakness is simple obscurity--virtually *nobody* will simply recognize this structure and understand how it works without at least a little study (and a few probably won't trust it even then). Less obviously, this technique is generally incompatible with automated (tracing-based) garbage collection. A garbage collector detects what memory is still accessible by traversing all accessible pointers. Without special knowledge about how to recover the actual pointers in the list, all but the first and last nodes of this list will appear inaccessible.

Nearly the sole real strength is what was stated up front: this lets you build a linked list that can be traversed in either direction while storing only (bits the same size as) one pointer per node. Since it can be traversed in either direction without modification, it avoids the reentrancy problems inherent in the original code.

Comment: Clever. I called it :) A doubly linked list would be well-suited. And the XOR trick is one devious trick. Oh, using `unique_ptr<>` in the node is prone to stack-overflow on default destruction. Don't forget to iteratively reset the nodes if you use it!

Answer (score 6):

While this a good example of a list reversal algorithm from a purely algorithmic point of view, the finer details with regards to the list and the reverse implementation are in need of some work.

---

The biggest problem here is that the proper tools haven't been used for abstraction and encapsulation of the list. In particular, you should have a `list` class that manages your sequence of `node`s rather than managing the `node`'s bare. This allows you much easier use, and it provides a much cleaner interface. Compare what you're doing to something as simple to use as:

```
list l;
l.add(3);
l.add(5);
```

This also gives the benefit of encapsulating memory management of the `node`s. Raw memory management with new and delete is extremely error prone and has all kinds of non-obvious caveats (exception safety, flow jumps can cause leaks, etc). Manual memory management should only be used in low level containers. Everything else should hide it behind RAII by either having a container manage it (like `list` managing `node`s) or through smart pointers (when a container doesn't make sense).

It should be noted that the higher level of abstraction does come at a cost to you, the developer. By alleviating the consumer's responsibility to manage the nodes, you must do it yourself behind the scenes of a few public methods. Also, in order to allow the consumer to examine the list, you would need to implement some form of iterator. Unfortunately, both of these things coupled together means that a `list` is going to be much more complicated than a set of `node`s. If your goal was just to demonstrate a simple reversal algorithm, a `list` would be overkill. Then again, if you had iterators, you could simply use a reverse iterator and you wouldn't need to actually reverse the list (though this would of course require a doubly linked list for the expected linear performance).

(Oh also, if you do make a `list`, don't use the name `list` unless you put it in namespace. Someone would inevitably drag your list and `std::list` into the global namespace, and it could end badly.)

---

Even if you don't make a full out `list` class, you should make some effort to abstract away the gritty details. The most obvious and straightforward way to do this is to use functions rather than operating on the list directly (`node* list_add(node* head, int data);`, `list_destroy(node* head);`, so on). Not only does this reduce code duplication (and thus the likelihood of fixing one section of code only to leave another broken), but it provides a better experience to use the list.

---

On a more stylistic/technical note, I would give `node` a constuctor. That allows you to save quite a bit of initialization code when creating nodes:

```
struct node { 
    int data;
    node *next;
    explicit node(int data, node *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next)
    { }
};
```

This allows much more succinct node creation:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    list = new node(i, list);
}
```

---

When there are simple conditions and post-actions, I find `for` loops easier to immediatley grasp than `while` loops:

```
void show_list(node *list) {
    for (; list != NULL; list = list->next) {
        std::cout << list->data << ", ";
    }
}
```

---

The semantics of your `reverse` strike me as a bit C. `list = reverse(list)` makes it look like a new copy of the list is created that is reversed. For example, imagine `node* newList = reverse(list)`. Without reading the code (as there is no documentation), it is not clear that `newList` is not copy of `list`. After this call, `list` is no longer safe to use, but nothing indicates this. It's just an unexpected side effect.

This usage seems a bit unnatural and prone to error. I would mutate the parameter to `reverse`. You can even still return it for the `list = reverse(list)` usage if you want (though I wouldn't since that brings back the ambiguity of whether or not a copy is made).

```
void reverse(node*& list) {
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *next;

    while (list) {
        next = list->next;
        list->next = prev;
        prev = list;
        list = next;
    }
    list = prev;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Code this valuable shouldn't be limited solely to `int` data.

```
template<typename T>
struct node { 
    T data;
    node *next;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to have a little more context for this code, to answer questions such as why you don't do something like this:

```
#include <list>
...
  std::list<int> my_list;
  ... put something in my_list to make a non-trivial test ...
  show_list(my_list);
  my_list.reverse();
  show_list(my_list);
```

There's also a singly-linked list, `slist`, if you want to avoid the double-linking of `std::list`, although I've previously found `slist` not as portable as `std::list`.  (That is, not everyone's implementation of the STL seemed to provide it.)

If it's really worth creating your own linked list, how about making a class called something like `List` containing objects of type `Node`, or implement these as templates `List<T>` and `Node<T>` as others have recommended? Then you can make `reverse()` be a member function of `List<T>` so that you can write something like:

```
List<T> my_list;
... other code ...
my_list.reverse();
```

A member function returning void would be my preferred way to modify an object "in place"--the function doesn't return anything, and in this case it doesn't even have parameters to play with, so it's clear the ONLY thing it can do is to modify the original list.  And notice that that's how list reversal is implemented in STL.